# Kibana - how to select first log line with same correlation id?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I know it's not strictly supported by ES, but in a lot of log troubleshooting scenarios I need to get a previous (or the first) document with the same request id (aka correlation id).

In a relational DB I would've simply JOINed. Of course in ES, join or any kind of subquery isn't supported. I could potentially script this outside ES, but I'm looking for a shortcut (either something built into Kibana UI, a ready script or some other inventive way).

Is there a way to use Kibana UI (as resource expensive as it needs to be) that can achieve the above? If not, is there a ready-made tool?

Before the XY-problem commenters jump in - since logging is inherently a time series, it's going to be hard to delay pushing log lines into ES until all information is known and the creating an aggregate. Even looking back for each log line to include the information from all the previous log lines "just in case it's needed" is prohibitively expensive and will cause the logging stack to become too slow to be functional.

So yes - ELK need to maintain one document per log line (more or less) and I **sometimes** need to be able to trace back and show aggregations over **related** log lines.